# understanding Elasticsearch query with elasticsearch-model ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a search form where I want someone to choose to enter in a query or not, then optionally enter in some sort of filter to get a result. So, dealing with 2 fields `name` and `city`, let's say someone searches "billy", and "Las Vegas". The user searching knows there is a name that has "billy" in it, but don't know if it's a first, middle, or last, or maybe it was a street name... The one thing the user knows for sure is that the record is in the `city` "Las Vegas".

Here is my query hash that gives me 0 results.

```
{
  query: {
    query_string: {
      query: 'billy'
    }
  },
  filter: {
   and: [
    {term: {city: 'Las Vegas'}}
   ]
 }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this. Instead of using the `elasticsearch-model` gem, use the [searchkick](http://searchkick.org/) gem. Tons easier to integrate and query.

```
Person.search("billy", where: {city: 'Las Vegas'})
```

This still uses elasticsearch, and returns the exact results I was looking for!